# Disjoint union of 3 connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

We have $\gamma(t)=((1+e \cos t) \cos t, (1+e \cos t) \sin t )$.

I want to show that if $|e|>1$ then the complement of the curve is the disjoint union  of three connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, two of which are bounded and one is unbounded.

So we consider points $a,b$ such that $\gamma (a)= \gamma (b)$.

Then $(1+ e \cos a) \cos a=(1+ e \cos b) \cos b$ and $(1+ e \cos a) \sin a=(1+ e \cos b) \sin b$.

Squaring we get $(1+ e \cos a)^2=(1+e \cos b)^2$ form which we get $a=2k \pi \pm b$ or $e (\cos a+ \cos b)=-2$.

If $a=2 k \pi$ then $a-b$ is a multiple of the period which is $2 \pi$.

If $a= 2k \pi-b$ then $1+ e \cos a=0$ or $\sin a=0$.

If reject $\sin a=0$ since again at this case $a-b$ is a multiple of the period.

If $1+ e \cos a=0$ do we deduce that $1+ e \cos b=0$?

Or could it also hold that $\cos b=0$?

Also how could we reject the solution $e (\cos a+ \cos b)=-2$ that we get?

Furthermore, how can we show that the complement of $\gamma$ is the disjoint union  of three connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, two of which are bounded and one is unbounded?

**EDIT**

How  could show that $\gamma(t)=((1+e \cos t) \cos t, (1+e \cos t) \sin t )$ is a Jordan curve for $|e|>1$ ?

Comment: Perhaps the [Jordan Curve Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem)

Comment: @Bob1123 Is it the only way?

Comment: There could be, but it would be rather complicated and essentially like trying to prove the Jordan Curve Theorem. I think the difficulty in this problem is to apply the Jordan Curve Theorem to a curve that intersects itself once.

Comment: @Bob1123 Ok, I will read it. I haven't got taught it. Do you have an idea for the other questions of my post?

Comment: @Bob1123 I found the following:  another name for a Jordan curve is a simple closed curve. $$$$
But for $|e|>1$ the curve has a self-intersection point. So it is not simple, right? So why can we use the Jordan Curve Theorem?

Comment: Correct. You cannot use the Jordan Curve Theorem as is, but you may be able to finagle the theorem to do your bidding. For instance, you could split up your curve into two simple curves that meet at a point, apply the theorem to those, and see what happens...

Comment: How do we split up the curve ? Could you explain it further to me? @Bob1123

Answer (score 0):

Plotting the curve, ( a limacon) you see that it resembles a circle, but  with  one internal loop inserted that encloses a smaller oval shape. To prove that the complement is the disjoint union of  three (not say two) connected open regions you might use the fact that the winding number  invariant  is constant on connected open components and argue that the winding number takes the values 0,1,2 on the three different pieces.

Comment: What is a winding number invariant?

Comment: @evinda It is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number